# Server responded: 403. How to get round this issue?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, http-status-code-403

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.otodom.pl/sprzedaz/mieszkanie/warszawa/'

def get_page(url):

    he = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}

    response = requests.get(url,headers=he)

    if not response.ok:
        print('Server responded:',response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
    return soup

get_page(url)
```

This is my code where I'm trying to gain access to the website but every time I got "Server responded 403". When I run the first time the code worked perfectly but now something blocking. I've tried almost every manner from a stack, change User-Agent, import  urllib.request, and so on.

Does anyone have some idea what's wrong?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/z7Ecijh.png

Comment: It could be that an automated anti-scraping system detected scraping and blocked following requests.

Comment: try using `he = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}
`

Comment: I've tried this as well but nothing change

Comment: @Adrian When writing code into a post on SO, please use ``` from now on instead of relying on indentation to delimit code. Especially for every language.